# JavaFX tableview to database

Tags: sqlite, javafx, tableview

So I got TableView A populated from SQLite DB. It works, so no point posting code. Then user selects items on this TableView and adds it to TableView B

```
@FXML
private TableView<productData> tableProduct2;  


public void addMeal() {
    productData selection = tableProduct.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (selection != null) {
        tableProduct2.getItems().add(new productData(selection.getName()+ " " + weightField.getText() + " g", String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getKcal())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getProtein())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getCarb())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100)), String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(selection.getFat())*(Float.parseFloat(weightField.getText())/100))));
        }

    updateSummary();       
}
```

Now I want this TableView B saved in DataBase Table... but honestly, I have no idea how to work this out. Any ideas, help, suggestions?

Comment: When you click the button for adding to the Table B, call a function that executes the query for inserting that row in the Database.

Comment: Damn.. havent thought about the simplest solution, thanks, it works great. However, I got another problem... cant put <code> tags here so maybe someone could take a look on this method http://pastebin.com/Vy2xyjTs It throws  org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "name": syntax error)

Comment: Edit your query like this: String query = "DELETE FROM " + db + " WHERE name = '" + name + "';